# jQuery Failed To Get HTML Input Value

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery script :

```
$('a.manage-content-link').click(function (e) {
var self = $(this),
    file = self.siblings('input[type="hidden.block-hidden-input"]').val();
var username = $("username").val();
var ids = $(this).attr('id'); 
self.next(".manage-content-wrap").find(".manage-content").load("test1.php?id="+ids+"&file="+file);
e.preventDefault();
});
```

and this HTML tags :

```
<li><input type="hidden" value="001" class="block-hidden-input" />
    <a href="#" id="manage-1" class="manage-content-link">
        <img src="images/web-block/web-block1.jpg"/>
        <span class="orange-notice">Click to Edit Content</span>    
    </a>
</li>
```

in the test1.php, I have this :

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

echo $file ."<br>";
echo $id ."<br>";
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

and here's what I got as an output :

```
undefined >> should be 001
manage-1
Hello World
```

why that script failed to get the Input Value (in this case : 001), but it successfully get 'ids' from a href' ID?

Answer (score 4):

Your selector got messed up a little:

```
self.siblings('input[type="hidden.block-hidden-input"]').val();
                               ^^^^^
```

Try this one instead:

```
self.siblings('input[type="hidden"].block-hidden-input').val();
```

Also, are you sure you have a `<username>` element?

```
var username = $("username").val();
```

Comment: @gdoron: Thanks, I missed that one.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong,

`file = self.siblings('input[type="hidden.block-hidden-input"]').val();`

It should be

`file = self.siblings('input[type="hidden"].block-hidden-input').val();`

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
file = self.siblings('input[type="hidden"].block-hidden-input').val();
```